# How turn off completely responsive features in bootstrap yeti template?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, yeti

I use this template for bootstrap http://bootswatch.com/yeti/, so I have bootstrap.css but I want turn off responsive features completely for web. I need advice - have I do some changes in css file, or in web template only? My web where I solving this problem http://playground.jsreport.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most general way to approach this is you would take the parent element, for instance with yeti, you take `.container` and give it a static width and force it with `!important`.

The most general way to approach this is to wrap everything in a container and give it a static width.

#### CSS

```
.not-responsive {
  width: 1200px
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="not-responsive">
  [Put everything inside of this element]
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried set "width: 1200px !important", but if I change the window size on the web there still appear the responsive features in menu. I don't know how i can stop it.. Do you have any idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try wrapping everything in another div and give that div a static width. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could set the with of the body

```
<style>
body {
    min-width: 960px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried set "width: 1200px !important", but if I change the window size on the web there still appear the responsive features in menu. I don't know how i can stop it.. I tried all put into one div and declared fix value also. Do you have any idea? Thank you so much.