# How turn off responsive navbar in bootstrap yeti template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, yeti

I use this template for bootstrap http://bootswatch.com/yeti/, so I have bootstrap.css but I want turn off responsive features completely for web. The main problem is in navbar - if I change the window size the navbar starts looks bad.

I need advice - have I do some changes in css file, or in web template only? My web where I solving this problem http://playground.jsreport.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How turn off completely responsive features in bootstrap yeti template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613676/how-turn-off-completely-responsive-features-in-bootstrap-yeti-template)

Comment: Yes, but I am still solving this problem in navbar.. And there no function. Have you got any idea?

Comment: Do you have code example? You can use the `not-responsive` class in the same div you have your `navbar` class and it should fix it.